# Writing BytesIO Data to File

Tags: python, encode

I managed to try to do some searches on the topic but didn't come across anything that could help resolve, unless I failed to implement the resolutions.

Essentially I am making use of a products API to go in and download a file in different formats; pdf, html, csv, etc. I have everything good up to the point where I have to write the data to the file. I was making use of the io module in order to write data to the buffers and then decode. But when I try to write the data to a file, I guess I am not doing it correctly because I get different errors when changing things around.

I am coding in Python:

```
# Iterate through formats to download each file
                for type, fileID in formats.iteritems():
                        data = download_files(type,id, fileID)
                        with io.open("Nessus_Reports/%s/%s/%s_%d.%s" %(date,name,name,id,type), 'wb') as file:
                                file.write(data)
```

Here is my code sample from the function that downloads the data.

```
            session.setopt(session.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
            session.setopt(session.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
            session.setopt(session.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
            session.perform()

            if type == 'pdf' or type == 'db':
                    data = buffer.getvalue()
            else:
                    data = buffer.getvalue().decode('utf-8')

            return data
```

Error message I get with this implementation is 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 1
6604: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace?  That'll tell you where in your code the problem is